How do we enable nestedFolders feature toggles in azure managed grafana?
How do we enable nestedFolders feature toggles in azure managed grafana?
I could not find the settings to enable feature toggle in the azure portal. I read through the documentation of Azure Managed Grafana and could not find anything related to this.
I found out that these settings needs to be enabled in the .ini file, but I could not find the way to set it up in azure managed grafana.
